# Distant work for designer

Tags: django, git, design-patterns, development-environment

I have django project with some additional libs (like geo and etc.) on my pc, and git. And I've a friend, who don't know nothing about programming and development. 
 And my question is:  **How can she make design for my project on distant?**  
 She will be a distant designer, and I don't know how to manage her work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about management, not programming.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about an issue unrelated to programming.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are quite a few ways that you can collaborate over a distance, though none that I know of that are django specific.

I assume that by designer you mean that your friend will be working on the HTML and CSS aspects of the project.

Since you are already using Git, you could setup a git repo (perhaps on Github or BitBucket) and instruct your friend on how to use it. Have your friend fork your project and then when they complete a template have them submit a pull request to combine it with the main fork. That will give you the opportunity to look over any changes and make sure there are no conflicts.

Some alternatives could be using DropBox, Team Foundation Server or even a Pastebin. You are really only limited by your imagination and willingness to commit to a platform.

Comment: thanks, I thought there is something more in it, like online development, without git, but ok

Comment: Your answer Is about collaborating on a whole project which you won't want to do if you just want someone doing the Web design. They just need a template to work to

Comment: There is no reason that these methods can't be used to collaborate on a single aspect of the project. Since the OP is already using Git it makes sense to have his partner to use it as well for it's phenomenal source control tools. Git is also flexible enough that if the OP so desired, he could have a Git with just the template aspects of the project for the designer to use. Additionally, options like Pastebin are not viable for collaborating on a whole project at all. They would instead be useful only with single pages at a time.